# how to run a job on the master as a different user?

Tags: jenkins

I have jenkins installed on a linux machine within tomcat behind Apache.
As a consequence jenkins runs as *tomcat*. The user *tomcat* is not configured properly to run the job.

How do I tell Jenkins to run a job as a different user on the same machine ?

Does it make sense to define a slave on the same machine but with a different user ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `su` or `sudo` to run as a different user inside a build step, but that comes with some security implications. If this is something you want to do regularly I would recommend that you define a slave on the same machine with the other user, as you have suggested. I am not aware of any plugins/extensions that would make this easier for you unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes would ssh into the account and instead of running `build.sh` run `ssh user@localhost build.sh`